# How can i group by student id

Tags: python, django

Please i would like anyone to help me out, tryna grouping this student result from the lecturer session so that lecturer can view each student based on the course student submitted i have successfully get a list but the list are not grouped by the student ids

here is the view for lecturer request

```
class LecturerListOfStudentResult(View):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    lecturer = Lecturers.objects.get(admin=request.user.id)
    result = LecturerCourse.objects.filter(lecturer=lecturer)
    context = {
        'question':result,
    }
    return render(request, 'superadmin/lecturer/list-result- 
     student.html', context)
```

Here is the list of all submitted student result view

```
class ListAllSubmittedAnswerByCourseRegister(View):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       lecturer = Lecturers.objects.get(admin=request.user.id)
       result = StudentSubmittedAnswer.objects.filter(lecturer=lecturer, 
        student=int(kwargs['id']))
    context = {'question':result}
    return render(request, 'superadmin/lecturer/list-all-result- 
    student.html', context)
```

here is the detailview for the list which i only get the count record

```
class LecturerListOfStudentResultDetail(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       student = Students.objects.get(admin=int(kwargs['id']))
       result = StudentSubmittedAnswer.objects.filter(student=student)
       skipped = StudentSubmittedAnswer.objects.filter(student=student,  
       right_answer='Not Submitted').count()
       attempted = StudentSubmittedAnswer.objects.filter
       (student=student).exclude(right_answer='Not Submitted').count()

       rightAns=0
       percentage=0
       for row in result:
          if row.question.right_opt == row.right_answer:
            rightAns+=1
       if len(result) > 0:
            percentage=(rightAns*100)/result.count()
        return render(request, 'superadmin/lecturer/view-result- 
        detail.html', {'result': result,'total_skipped': 
        skipped,'attempted': attempted, 'rightAns': rightAns, 
        'percentage':percentage})
```

Here is my url.py

```
path('lecturer/course/registration', 
     LecturerCourseRegistration.as_view(), name="lecturer-course- 
     registration"),
path('list/lecturer/course/registration', 
    ListLecturerCourseRegistration.as_view(), name="list-lecturer- 
    course-registration"),
path('list/submitted/course/answer/student/<int:id>/', 
    ListAllSubmittedAnswerByCourseRegister.as_view(), name="list-all- 
    submitted-course-question-by-student"),
```

here is the list of student html

```
{% for r in question %}
   <tr>
     <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.course.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.created_at }}</td>
        <td><a  href="{% url 'emisapp:list-all-submitted-course- 
    question-by-student' r.lecturer.admin.id %}">View</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the html view for looping all the exam submitted for each student

```
{% for row in result %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
       <td>{{ row.course.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ row.question.question }}</td>
       <td>{{ row.question.right_opt }}</td>
        {% if row.question.right_opt == row.right_answer %}
           <td class="bg-success text-white">{{ row.right_answer }}</td>
                              {% else %}
           <td class="bg-danger text-white">{{ row.right_answer }}</td>
                              {% endif %}
           </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Models.py

```
class StudentSubmittedAnswer(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  course = models.ForeignKey(Courses)
  lecturer = models.ForeignKey(Lecturers)
  question = models.ForeignKey(QuizQuestion)
  student = models.ForeignKey(Students)
  right_answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Here is my added Models.py

```
class StudentSubmittedAnswer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lecturercourse = models.ForeignKey(LecturerCourse, null=True, 
    related_name='studentsubmittedanswer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lecturer = models.ForeignKey(Lecturers, null=True, 
    related_name='studentsubmittedanswer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(QuizQuestion, 
    related_name='studentsubmittedanswer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students, 
    related_name='studentsubmittedanswer', null=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    right_answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class Faculty(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   objects = models.Manager()

class Department(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, default=None)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
   short_desc = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class Courses(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    faculty = models.ManyToManyField(Faculty, related_name='courses')
     department = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    short_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    long_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


class StudentFaculty(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students, null=True)
    studentfaculty = models.ForeignKey('Faculty') 
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class StudentDepartment(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   student = models.ForeignKey(Students)
   studentfaculty = models.ForeignKey(StudentFaculty)
   studentdepartment = models.ForeignKey(Department)
   slug = models.SlugField(null=True)

class StudentCourses(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  student = models.ForeignKey(Students)
  studentfaculty = models.ForeignKey(StudentFaculty)
  studentdepartment = models.ForeignKey('StudentDepartment')
  studentcourse = models.ForeignKey(Courses)

class QuizQuestion(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  lecturer  = models.ForeignKey(Lecturers)
  faculty = models.ForeignKey(LecturerFaculty, null=True)
  lecturerdepartment = models.ForeignKey(LecturerDepartment, null=True)
  lecturercourse = models.ForeignKey(LecturerCourse)
  session = models.ForeignKey(SessionYearModel)
  semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester, null=True)
  mark = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  examtype = models.ForeignKey('ExamType', related_name='quizzes')
   question = models.TextField()
  opt_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  opt_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  opt_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  opt_4 = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class LecturerFaculty(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   lecturer = models.ForeignKey('Lecturers', 
   related_name='lecturerfaculty', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   faculty = models.ForeignKey('Faculty')
   slug = models.SlugField(null=True)

class LecturerDepartment(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   lecturer = models.ForeignKey('Lecturers')
   lecturerfaculty = models.ForeignKey('LecturerFaculty')
   lecturerdepartment = models.ForeignKey('Department')

class LecturerCourse(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   lecturer = models.ForeignKey('Lecturers')
   faculty = models.ForeignKey('Faculty')
   lecturerdepartment = models.ForeignKey('LecturerDepartment')
   lecturercourse = models.ForeignKey('Courses')
   slug = models.SlugField(null=True)


class Lecturers(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg')
   middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values` and `annotate` to group by student Ids.

```
class ListAllSubmittedAnswerByCourseRegister(View):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       lecturer = Lecturers.objects.get(admin=request.user.id)
      => result = StudentSubmittedAnswer.objects.values('student','lecturer').annotate(answers_count=Count('answers')).filter(lecturer=lecturer, 
        student=int(kwargs['id'])).order_by()
    context = {'question':result}
    return render(request, 'superadmin/lecturer/list-all-result- 
    student.html', context)
```

I assumed the name of the fields in the model `student` `answers` `lecturer`

### Refrence

Django documentation: values(), annotate(), and Count
Django documentation: Aggregation, and in particular the section entitled Interaction with default ordering or order_by()

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses

Comment: Thank you @Abdelaziz El-emary for this answer, but i find it weird getting this error, have troubleshoot, but kind of not knowing where the problem come from, i got this issue now do not know where the issue come from probably from the template or something,                   NoReverseMatch at /list/submitted/course/answer/student/2/
Reverse for 'view-result-of-student' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['view/student/result/by/lecturer/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Comment: Add the code for your models in the question maybe it is an issue with the relations between tables

Comment: Thank you @Abdelaziz, Please check the trend below, just added my model for the said object

Comment: i need to know why the values is displaying 1 instead of the exact value name when looping the distinct value